# Bootstrap popover on svg

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, svg

According to [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_popover.asp), in order to make a popover appear next to a link, all I need to use is this HTML:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-content="Some content inside the popover">Toggle popover</a>
```

My question is this:  How would I make a popover appear when I click on an svg element?  I tried this:

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-content="Some content inside the popover">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
    </a>
</svg>
```

Basically, all I did was stick an svg shape in the link, but it does not work.
How do I make a popover appear when I click on an svg?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured out the solution. When making a popover, bootstrap generates a div element inside the parent container. Obviously, that doesn't work right when its inside a svg. So here is the solution, give it a `data-container` set as `body` You can also get rid of the a element, and just add it directly to the circle element.

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <a data-toggle="popover" data-container="body" title="Popover Header" data-content="Some content inside the popover" data-placement="right">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
  </a>
</svg>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   
});
</script>
```

Comment: The problem is I want to have multiple different svg shapes to have different popovers.  And I need all of the shapes to be inside one svg element.

Comment: CyberBurst I have updated my answer, and it works now. It will allow you to set it for each shape to have its own popover :)

Comment: Just in case anyone is trying to do this with bootstrap 5, remember to change the attribute names to "data-bs-" rather than just "data-"

Answer (score 1):

Move  data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-content="Some content inside the popover" to SVG.It will work.

Comment: While this does work, I really want the data-toggle="popover" and so on, to be on my circle element.  And when I add it to the circle it still does not work.

Comment: Try this. When you call popover give container as body.

Comment: $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({container:'body'});

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't clear to me from the accepted answer above, but you can put any element in the `data-container=""`.  For example, if your SVG lives inside some `<div class="svg-container></div>`, you can put this class as the value for the 'data-container', like this: 
`data-container=".svg-container"`.  This is better than put `data-container="body"` as a value because in that case all the popovers will be in the very bottom of the body with some unwanted/unexpected behavior (e.g. when page is resized).

Answer (score 0):

Try put this inside your script tag

```
$("circle").popover({trigger:'hover', placement:'bottom', title:'Title!', content:'Content'});
```

Answer (score 0):

2022+ Bootstrap 5+

```
<a class="d-inline-block" tabindex="0" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-trigger="click hover" 
title="Dismissible popover" data-bs-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">
   <svg ....
   </svg>
</a>
```

`class="d-inline-block"` solves the problem!